# How to rewrite a file URL in a reverse proxy upstream to a host local path?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I setup a Nginx reverse proxy virtual host as below:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Now, I'd like to add a special file URL in the proxy upstream to a file in the nginx host file system, i.e.

```
rewrite /rwt-resources/themes/images/676b22ad.png /file/path/under/the/nginx/host.png permanent;
```

How to make it?

Comment: What happenned when you tested the change you proposed? How did this not meet your requirement? (I suspect that you don't want a HTTP redirect here, in which case use  'break' or 'last' rather than 'permanent'). And you're heading for a world of pain trying to content management in your webserver / proxy config.

Comment: I test, it failed for being not able to redirect to the nginx host local file path.

Comment: So you want one URL to **not** go to `proxy_pass`? Use `location = /rwt-resources/themes/images/676b22ad.png { ... }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank you for your tip! I add a location before location /. However, it said 404 in the Developer tools.
    location /rwt-resources/themes/images/676b22ad.png {
        internal;
        alias /root/seb/;
    }

    location / {
.......

Comment: `internal` will respond with 404 if the request is external - you should probably remove it. The alias statement should probably be `alias /file/path/under/the/nginx/host.png;`

Comment: Thank you! However it said 403 error. Even I ran `chown -R www-data:www-data /root/seb`.